# Windows 7 and XP Networking

Tags: windows-7, networking, home-networking, hub

I'm trying to setup a home network between a windows 7 and windows xp machine. I have a small hub. My XP computer has a manually assigned IP address (192.168.0.10) and I set my Windows 7 machine to have a manually assigned IP address (192.168.0.15). The XP computer works, but the Windows 7 machine does not see the network. It says that there is no connectivity.

Ping does not work from either machine.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you get internet on either or both machines?

Comment: Is the link-active light on for the hub where the W7 cable is plugged in?  Is the W7 NIC card's link-active light (assuming it has one) on when plugged in?  What is the netmask of your LAN?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a hub or a switch, make sure that there is no ip address assigned for the gateway on the LAN interfaces on either machine.

If it's a router, make sure that you have configured the router already.